# How to show particular text in textbox using JQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am using the following code to calculate the avg value from a total of 5 different inputs.

```
var total = p1 + p2 + p3 + p4 + p5;
var priority = total / 5;
```

I am trying to show "High", "Medium" and "Low" inside a textbox based on the value of the variable priority:

I have used this code, but nothing seems to be correct, plz help:

```
if (5 > priority > 4)
{
    $("#textbox").val('High');
} else if (4 > priority > 2.5)
{
    $("#textbox").val('Medium');
} else if (2.5 > priority > 0)
{
    $("#textbox").val('Low');
}
```

Comment: Try evaluating your logical conditions in the debugger to see what's happening, so you actually understand the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.val(function)`, conditional operator; if `priority` is greater than `4` set element `value` to `"High"`; if `priority` is greater than `2.5` set value to `"Medium"`; else set value to `"Low"`

```
$("#textbox").val(_, function(val) {
  return priority > 4 ? "High" : priority > 2.5 ? "Medium" : "Low"
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (5 > priority > 4)
```

is not the correct way to test if `priority` is between `5` and `4`. The expression is parsed as `5 > (priority > 4)`. `(priority > 4)` evaluates to `true` or `false`, which is then converted to `1` or `0` when comparing with `5`. So this will be either `5 > 1` or `5 > 0`, and they're both true.

The correct way is:

```
if (5 > priority && priority > 4)
```

But there's really no need to test if `priority` is between values at all. Each `else if` only runs if the previous `if` failed.  So if you get to the second `if`, you've already excluded the case where `priority > 4`, so you don't need to test it again. Also, none of your cases will succeed when `priority` is exactly equal to one of the boundary values; when `priority == 4`, it will be excluded by both `priority > 4` and `priority < 4`. So just check one end of the range and the other end will take care of itself.

So the code should be:

```
if (priority > 4) {
    $("#textbox").val("High");
} else if (priority > 2.5) {
    $("#textbox").val("Medium");
} else {
    $("#textbox").val("Low");
}
```